# For the Device-Mapper framework, who is doing the development, and how do you contribute to it?

Tags: device-mapper

I've been using the device-mapper framework (dm-crypt, dm-verity), but there are some things I wish could be improved.

Where is the discussion about its development and is there a way to contribute to it?

Answer (score 2):

For the userspace portion of cryptsetup (since you mentioned dm-crypt), you can contribute to cryptsetup on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/), or start a discussion at [cryptsetup@lists.linux.dev](https://lore.kernel.org/cryptsetup/).

For DM itself, you want [dm-devel](https://listman.redhat.com/mailman/listinfo/dm-devel), which takes both patches in `git format-patch` style and discussions.